# how to convert android APK file to JAR file and run it on pc with java runtime?

Tags: apk, java

Here is the deal, I have a Apk file, just can run on android phone. Now I take the Apk I want,  decompile it or do something can change Apk file to Jar file. Jar file will be a java execution, can run on pc with java software. Are people understand? So, how to do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible at all. You can convert an APK or the DEX inside to a JAR for decompiling purpose ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478809/android-java-proguard-how-to-verify-if-my-jar-different-jar-project-apk-ar/7478874#7478874)). But is it not possible to run APKs in your PC by directly converting it to JAR (there are huge dependency issues which differ in PC and android).

If your target is to just run your android apps in PC, you can use any android compatibility layer like [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/).

Comment: but i said : JAR executation.  not for use. just hacking test for fun. exstract jar from apk know that. but jar file can't run.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I have also tried to do the same. But I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: is it work, Atanu Roy? How can I do it?